# GUI buttons for drawing standard geometrical shapes

Tags: texstudio, editors

In any tex editor e.g. Texstudio, there are various GUI buttons for various commands e.g. for BOLD , Italic, Centering etc. Are there similar types of GUI buttons/ shortcuts for drawing standard geometrical shapes like rectangles, circles etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TexStudio is to broad latex aplication and is code oriented, but yes, it has buttons to insert some codes for pstricks and tikz.

[image]

Another ad hoc option for drawings is tikzedt that has code snippets but I use only to remember some colors and styles because the semi WYSIWYG mode is usefull to understand code behavior.

[image]

Finally the best way is undesrtanding the drawing codes, in the latex philosophy, where you order the program what to do, and to know what to say to latex, an useful manual is [VisualTikz](http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf)